# asp.net iis8 app is not loading when using forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms, authentication

Am using forms authentication. When I tested the app using Visual studio, it all worked fine. But when I created a VD and application in IIS and tried to browse, it just hangs up and the browser is unresponsive. VERY URGENT, Please help

authorization deny users ="?"

Comment: How is your forms auth configured? Additionally, how is IIS configured for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to browse your application using different browsers?
How did you configure the IIS Server? How's the settings of the Virtual Directory?

If the browser just hangs up when you try to load your application, there are several factors that we need to consider: IIS Server setup/settings, database, web browser, etc.